# Local Unit Tests with SparseIntArray and others from android.util.*

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

The Android Studio recommends me to use [`SparseIntArray`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseIntArray.html) instead of `Hashmap<Integer, Integer>` from standard Java.

> [`SparseIntArray`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseIntArray.html) map integers to integers. Unlike a normal array of integers, there can be gaps in the indices. It is intended to be more memory efficient than using a HashMap to map Integers to Integers, both because it avoids auto-boxing keys and values and its data structure doesn't rely on an extra entry object for each mapping.

I think it really fits my code, but I cannot use any methods containing this class in [Local Unit Tests](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html). I always end with RuntimeException...

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method put in android.util.SparseIntArray not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
   at android.util.SparseIntArray.put(SparseIntArray.java)
   ...
```

Is there any way to import this method for local testing? I don't think it uses any Android's features. The `unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true` only returns default values for all calls. I know I can use [Instrumented Unit Tests](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html) but it slows down the testing process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Robolectric framework if you want to test class with platform dependencies: http://robolectric.org/